# Detect user entered same placeholder text in UITextView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Using UITextView by setting text as placeholder

```
textView.text = UIColor.black // Added in viewDidLoad

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if (textView.text == "ADD") {
       textView.text = ""
       textView.textColor = .black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if (textView.text == "") {
       textView.text = "ADD"
       textView.textColor = .gray
    }
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
}

func appendBtnTap() {
     if textView.text != "" && textView.text != "ADD" {
        appendData()
     } else {
        // Show error to enter text
     }
}
```

Above code works fine, but on an edge case, if user enters the text same as Placeholder text which is "ADD" and tap Append button, it will show an error. How to avoid this

One solution I got from surfing is checking the textColor(gray or black). Is that the proper way to do

Comment: replace `textView.text != "ADD"` this condition with `textView.textColor != .gray`

Comment: How does func appendBtnTap() come into play?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different delegate method to reset the text if it is the same as the placeholder.

```swift
textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)
```

Answer (score 0):

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText string: String) -> Bool {
let oldText = txtViewDescription.text!
let newText = (oldText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

if oldtext == newText {
return
}

you can check the old value and the new value user entered if both are same then this delegate method return and nothing happend :)